# What would cause a standard object to load slowly?

Tags: opportunity, timeout

I'm working in a sandbox(**salesforce classic layout**) where opening an Opportunity record would sometimes hit the time limit(2 minutes). I'm trying to figure out why that's happening.

[image]

[image]

I've never seen this before so I am trying to come up with some ideas. I looked in workbench and I noticed that the Opportunity object has 110+ children. Also the Opportunity has 700+ fields.

On another note there's 2 managed packages that are loaded(through vf pages) into the standard page layout so I am wondering if that could happen due to the managed package trying to load some resources that are taking too long and salesforce is waiting for that process to complete first.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: try removing the VF sections for the managed packages and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of fields and objects trying to load, this could cause performance problems. There's an article on [how to improve performance](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000148978&language=en_US&type=1) you should take a look at. This article mentions accounts, but can be used for any misbehaving object that has too many fields and objects. Here's some things to try:

> By checking the "Enable Separate Loading of Related Lists", a detailed record is displayed first and then its Related Lists are loaded.
>
> If some of Related Lists are not used so often by end users, please consider removing these Related Lists or replacing them with custom links to these pages.
>
> Please consider minimizing the number of displayed fields on each Related List.
>
> Please reduce the number of records in Objects used in Related Lists.  As a best practice, 10K is a threshold.

There's a few other tips there, too, but simply enabling the "separate loading of related lists" feature and removing unnecessary related lists should drastically improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this link, I will go through it!